# Is there a generic equivalent of pciv_vf_config in the linux kernel driver environment

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, pci

I have a SR-IOV based PCIe device.  I would like to find a "supported" method for recovering the number of VF's (virtual functions) in a PCIe PF (physical function).  I found in the oracle documentation, that there is a function called `priv_vf_config()` that can return a structure that contains an element with the number of vf's included.  Is there a generic equivalent of this type of function in one of standard linux includes for kernel development?

Answer (score 1):

From [drivers/pci/iov.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/pci/iov.c#L657):

```c
/**
 * pci_num_vf - return number of VFs associated with a PF device_release_driver
 * @dev: the PCI device
 *
 * Returns number of VFs, or 0 if SR-IOV is not enabled.
 */
int pci_num_vf(struct pci_dev *dev)
```

Include `<linux/pci.h>` header in your module to declare above function.

Also be sure to enable `CONFIG_PCI_IOV` in your kernel configuration:

```
config PCI_IOV
    bool "PCI IOV support"
    depends on PCI
    help
      I/O Virtualization is a PCI feature supported by some devices
      which allows them to create virtual devices which share their
      physical resources.
```